# How to change a list to be used as a dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists with 4 elements in each of them.

```
LoL=[[1,1,1,1],[4,2,3,[1,3]],[4,5,3,[0,4]]]
```

The 4th elements can be a list of two parts like `[0,4]` in `[4,5,3,[0,4]]`.

I need to use its elements as keys for a dictionary,

```
Pseudo code:
dic = { [1,1,1,1]:'a',[4,2,3,[1,3]]:'b',[4,5,3,[0,4]]:'c' }
```

so tried to change them to `tuple`s.
It works for simple lists (like `[1,1,1,1]`), but for the ones containing another list (like `[4,5,3,[0,4]]`) it raises an error:

```
dic[tuple([1,1,1,1])]=['bla','blah']
print dic
{(1, 1, 1, 1): ['bla', 'blah']}

dic[tuple([4, 2, 3, [1, 3]])]=['blablah']
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I need to reuse the keys as lists later. So trying to change elements of LoL to strings (e.g. using `repr()`) is not an option!

Edit:
I know why lists cannot be used as dictionary keys. Here they are not changed while in the `dic`. I just need some way to pass them to another module to extract them.

Comment: I have read that, I know why! and how tuples didn't solve my problem.

Comment: The LoL is passed to my program and I can't change it. It is input to my module.

Comment: @vaultah : Angel _knows_ they can't use lists as keys, but wants to know how to get around that, which your links don't fully address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your nested lists to nested tuples. Here's a quick demo. It's not perfect, but it works.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

LoL = [[1,1,1,1],[4,2,3,[1,3]],[4,5,3,[0,4]]]

def nested_list_to_tuple(nlist):
    return tuple([nested_list_to_tuple(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in nlist]) 

ToT = nested_list_to_tuple(LoL)

print ToT
```

**output**

```
((1, 1, 1, 1), (4, 2, 3, (1, 3)), (4, 5, 3, (0, 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use tuples:

```
a = {}
a[(4, 2, 3, (1, 3))] = ['blablah']
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{(4, 2, 3, (1, 3)): ['blablah']}
```

Comment: LoL values are passed to my module. And I cannot change them.

Comment: @Angel. You can preprocess input to tuple `>>> l
[1, 2, 4, (3, 4)]
>>> def convert_to_tuple(l):
 for i in range(len(l)):
  if isinstance(l[i], list):
   l[i] = tuple(l[i])
 return tuple(l)

>>> convert_to_tuple(l)
(1, 2, 4, (3, 4))`